# Java: my array returns 0, why?

Tags: java, arrays

I have been struggling with this all day-long and can't find a suitable method yet.
I defined my arrays as follows:

```
public String month()
    {
        return birth.substring(3, 5);

    }
public int beers()
    {
    return nbBeer;
    }
```

Then I put this in my public class

```
    static int julyBeer(Personne[] perso, int nbElem)
                {
                    int i;
                    int k = 0;
                    for(i=0; i < nbElem; i++)
                        if(perso[i].month() == "07" && perso[i].beers() >= 1)
                            k++;
                    return k;   


        public static void main (String[] args){


            Personne[] pers = { new Personne("10/07/1999", 3), new
    Personne("19/02/1993", 2), new Personne("22/10/1988", 5), new
        Personne("10/06/1994", 4),  new Personne("02/07/1990", 2)};

int nbElem = pers.length;
    int beerMin = 1;

System.out.printf("Beer in July: %d", julyBeer(pers, nbElem));
                }
    }
```

And the outcome is: 
Beer in July: 0, and it's supposed to return 2.

Comment: Issue is in  if(perso[i].month() == "07" && perso[i].beers() >= 1). Use equals method.

Comment: Thanks Shayan, I tried to use the same that I'd use in C. I will take a look into the equal method.